# CakePhp uploading multiple images

Tags: php, cakephp, image-uploading

I'm trying to save a multiple input file I´m receiving from a form. But the structure is not what I expected... Here is the structure:

```
Array
(
    [files] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 25th birthday.PNG
                    [1] => 1535UDEM-info-2011.jpg
                    [2] => 2012-06-11 14.49.48.jpg
                    [3] => 
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => image/png
                    [1] => image/jpeg
                    [2] => image/jpeg
                    [3] => 
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /tmp/php0GW7d6
                    [1] => /tmp/phpwzS0DO
                    [2] => /tmp/phpMifC4w
                    [3] => 
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 0
                    [3] => 4
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 159487
                    [1] => 528765
                    [2] => 822193
                    [3] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

Could cakephp save this type of array? If so, how? I´m using http://cakephp-upload.readthedocs.org this plugin to upload the image. I think I must save one by one, but I´m not sure how to. Im trying to rename each image with this code:

```
foreach ($imageFiles['name'] as $key => $value) {
    if(!empty($value))
    {
        $file = $imageFiles['url']; //put the data into a var for easy use
        $ext = substr(strtolower(strrchr($file['name'], '.')), 1); //get the extension
        $randomCode = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 5, 5);
        $imageFiles['url']['name'] = date('Y-m-d')."_".$randomCode.".".$ext;
    } else {
        $imageFiles['url'] = "";
    }

}
```

Could someone give me advice on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But the structure is not what I expected

What did you expect? The "normal" structure? You need to normalize the array, well don't have to but normalizing it makes working with it a lot easier and you can just do a foreach and save each file the same way, no matter if one or many are present.

See https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-file-storage/blob/3.0/src/Lib/FileStorageUtils.php

```
/**
 * Method to normalize the annoying inconsistency of the $_FILE array structure
 *
 * @link http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php#109437
 * @param array $array
 * @return array Empty array if $_FILE is empty, if not normalize array of Filedata.{n}
 */
    public static function normalizeGlobalFilesArray($array = null) {
        if (empty($array)) {
            $array = $_FILES;
        }
        $newfiles = array();
        if (!empty($array)) {
            foreach ($array as $fieldname => $fieldvalue) {
                foreach ($fieldvalue as $paramname => $paramvalue) {
                    foreach ((array)$paramvalue as $index => $value) {
                        $newfiles[$fieldname][$index][$paramname] = $value;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return $newfiles;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

A better solution to Upload images or Files is Dropzone.js . Its really nice ans easy to use and also includes PHP for the Upload.

Comment: That's a comment, not an answer nor would this probably solve his problem with multiple files in a very CakePHPish way. In fact most uploders php scripts suck because they're thought as examples.